# How can i make sessionid expire?

Tags: integration

As i logged in with my login credentials in my application.I entered in landing page.But when i copying same url & pasted in another browser.it is not asking login credentials directly opening into landing page. 
My requirement is it should ask login creditionals.

Comment: If you copied the URL which contains the access token you might be able to login however if you landed at home page and tried to login by copying home URL in other browser, ideally you should not be able to login unless you have an active session in other browser.